# ActiveRecord won't build the right class using STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sti

I'm using single table inheritance in my application and running into problems building inherited users from an ancestor. For instance, with the following setup:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  attr_accessible :type #etc...

  belongs_to :school

end

Class Instructor < User

   attr_accessible :terms_of_service
   validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true

end


Class Student < User

end
```

How can I build either a `instructor` or `student` record from an instance of **School**? Attempting something like `School.first.instructors.build(....)` gives me a new **User** instance only and I won't have access to instructor specific fields such as `terms_of_service` causing errors later down the rode when generating instructor-specific forms, building from console will give me an mass-assignment error (as it's trying to create a **User** record rather than an **Instructor** record as specified). I gave the example of **School**, but there are a few other associations that I would like to inherit from the User table so I don't have to repeat code or fields in the database. Am I having this problem because associations can not be shared in an STI setup?

Comment: Associations are being shared in STI relationships, but School doesn't know about that, you have to implement new one for school like in the next answer.

Comment: Tried that, do I have to add any additional fields to the database for to get that approach to work? (Which would kind of defeat the purpose of STI)

Comment: No, just set up STI correctly: with field 'type' datatype string, reload environment. It should work. If not, provide more code for us to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems part of the problem stemmed from having the old `users` association inside of my **School** model. Removing that and adding the associations for students and instructors individually worked.

Updated **School.rb**:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  #removed:
  #has_many :users this line was causing problems

  #added
  has_many :instructors
  has_many :students

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify instructors explicitly

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users
  has_many :instructors,:class_name => 'Instructor', :foreign_key => 'user_id'

end
```

Comment: Didn't work, I added that code and ran `School.last.instructors.build(:terms_of_service => true)` and got a mass assignment error because it still thinks it's a user record.

Comment: @Cyle Try also specifying a type when build
`School.first.instructors.build(type: 'Instructor')`

Comment: @Cyle You can also try saying
`user = School.first.instructors.build(....);
user.becomes('Instructor')`

Comment: Hmm, your last snippet produces the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for "Instructor":String`

Comment: @Cyle sorry `user.becomes(Instructor)`

Comment: That seems to have worked, but then I'll have to manually assign each instructor field individually in my controller which isn't exactly desirable. Unless there is a way to assign a hash to the user variable?

Comment: Guys, you don't have these stuff, and you don't have to :class_name => 'Instructor', :foreign_key => 'user_id'. Why :user_id? Foreign key for this association must be `:school_id`. In other words just `has_many :instructors`. and thats it.

Comment: @ValeryKvon I feel it should be that easy as well. I made those changes but it still doesn't quite work. I ran this in console `School.last.instructors` and it executed this SQL `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."school_id" = 1 AND "users"."type" = 'instructor'` why is it looking for type in lowercase? Shouldn't it be `AND "users"."type" = 'Instructor'`? Maybe it's an ActiveRecord bug?

Comment: Yes it must be capitalized. Ok, lets get some tests: `Instructor.new(:terms_of_service => 'agreed')`, `User.new(:terms_of_service => 'agreed')`,`School.new.users.build(:terms_of_service => 'agreed')`, `School.new.instructors.build(:terms_of_service => 'agreed')`

Comment: `School.new.users.build.class`, `School.new.instructors.build.class`

Comment: And you have strange SQL statement. Rails 2 or more must generate something like that: `"users"."type" IN ('Instructor')`

Comment: I'm using Postgresql, maybe that's why? If I do `Instructor.new` it sets the type as `Instructor` with a capital.

Comment: I use Postgres too, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: OK, I solved the problem. Had to remove the `has_many :users` association. I up-voted both @ValeryKvon 's answer and this one as they were both pretty close.

Comment: It sucks, it must be working with both ) The problem is somewhere else )

Comment: Maybe another The Brand New Rails Version 3.3.15 has a couple of stupid bugs. Rails is really need the good CoreDev management...

Answer (score 1):

And what else:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :instructors
end

class Instructor < User 
  attr_accessible :terms_of_service # let it be at the first place. :)

  validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true
end
```